# Where do AppSettings go in web.config?

Tags: asp.net

I've got a very old asp.net program and it has some AppSettings in the web.config file.

But it looks like the XML structure has changed a bit. It's unclear where I should put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a direct child of the `<configuration>` node.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration> 
    <appSettings> 
        <add key="SiteName" value="My Awesome Website" /> 
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

To access them, I personally prefer caching them in a static class to avoid repeated configuration/NVC lookups:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public static class GlobalSettings
{
    static public string SiteName { get; set; }

    static GlobalSettings()
    {
        SiteName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteName"];
    }
}
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtPageTitle.Text = GlobalSettings.SiteName;
}
```

---

Read more here: [Microsoft Docs - appSettings Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms228154(v=vs.100))